# Python: how can I get a mutable slice pointing to a byte array?

Tags: python, python-2.7, io

I want a version of [`buffer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#buffer) which points to a [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray) and is *mutable*.  I want to pass it to I/O functions like [`io.BufferedIOBase.readinto()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase.readinto) without an overhead of memory allocation in a loop.

```
import sys, struct

ba = bytearray(2000)
lenbuf = bytearray(8)

with open(sys.argv[1]) as fp:
  while True:
    fp.readinto(lenbuf)  # efficient version of fp.read(8)
    dat_len = struct.unpack("Q", lenbuf)
    buf = buffer(ba, 0, dat_len)
    fp.readinto(buf)  # efficient version of fp.read(dat_len), but
                      # yields TypeError: must be read-write buffer, not buffer
    my_parse(buf)
```

I also tried `buf =`[`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview-type)`(buffer(ba, 0, length))` but got (essentially) the same error.

I believe using Python shouldn't be synonymous to paying little attention to runtime performance.

I use Python 2.6 installed on Cent6 by default but can switch to 2.7 or 3.x if really necessary.

Thanks!

### Update <- no, this is not the way to go

<s>I'm perplexed by the behavior of a slice into `bytearray`.  The below transcript suggests I can simply take a slice out of a `bytearray`:</s>

```
>>> x = bytearray(10**8)
>>> cProfile.run('x[10:13]="abc"')
         2 function calls in 0.000 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}

>>> x.count(b'\x00')
3999999997
>>> len(x)
4000000000

>>> cProfile.run('x[10:13]="abcd"')  # intentionally try an inefficient case
         2 function calls in 0.750 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.750    0.750    0.750    0.750 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}

>>> len(x)
4000000001
```

But, the "mutable slice" doesn't work as expected under assignment of a single byte:

```
>>> x = bytearray(4*10**9)
>>> x = bytearray(10)
>>> x[2] = 0xff
>>> x.count(b'\x00')
9
>>> x[3:5][0] = 0xff
>>> x.count(b'\x00')
9  # WHAT
```

I will not really use a single byte assignment in my application, but I'm concerned if there's any fundamental misunderstanding.

Comment: why do you need a buffer when all the functions you mention are  actually expecting a bytearray?

Comment: Because those I/O functions try to fill as long as `len(buf)` bytes but I want to keep reusing a single "long enough" buffer (`bytearray(2000)`)

Comment: I'm curious to see if there are any performance improvement between your code and @ALGOholic code. Because frankly, with garbage collection, trying to fix the supposed overhead of memory allocation is rather bold.

Answer (score 1):

You could let it read excess data and then simply use all excess data from your bytearray before reading more from file.

Otherwise you can use numpy:

```
import sys, struct
import numpy as np

buf = np.zeros(2000, dtype=np.uint8)
lenbuf = bytearray(8)

with open(sys.argv[1]) as fp:
    while True:
        fp.readinto(lenbuf)
        dat_len = struct.unpack("Q", lenbuf)
        fp.readinto(buf[:dat_len])
        my_parse(buf[:dat_len])
```

numpy creates the read-write buffers you need and indexing [:dat_len] returns a "view" of subset of the data rather than copy. Since numpy arrays conform to buffer protocol you can further use them with struct.unpack() as if they were bytearrays/buffers.

Comment: "You could let it read excess data and then simply use all excess data from your bytearray before reading more from file." Sorry but you're essentially saying I should implement buffered I/O myself here.

But thanks for letting me know about NumPy array type.